# sysmalloc: Assertion ....... failed. Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: arrays, c, tree, malloc, implicit-conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>



typedef struct a{ 
    char * word ;
    int occurs;
    struct a * left;
    struct a * same;
    struct a * right; } Node; 
    
typedef Node * Node_ptr ;
typedef Node * TriTree ;

void inorder(TriTree x) {
    if(x==NULL) return;
    inorder(x->left);
    printf("%s(%d)--" , x->word, x->occurs);
    inorder(x->same);
    inorder(x->right);
    return;}

void strlower(char * lower){
    for (char *p = lower; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
    printf("%s\n",lower);
};
// 1
Node_ptr create(char * word){
    Node_ptr tmp_ptr;
    tmp_ptr = (Node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node_ptr));
    tmp_ptr-> word = word;
    tmp_ptr-> occurs = 1;
    tmp_ptr-> left = NULL;
    tmp_ptr-> same = NULL;
    tmp_ptr-> right = NULL;
    return tmp_ptr;
}


int main()
{
    char a[]="Stelios";

    strlower(&a);

    Node_ptr tmp;
    
    tmp = create(&a);
    printf(tmp->word);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to write a structure about ternary tree and methods to create nodes, insert nodes etc.

When I run this code as it is its fine! when i comment the line // strlower(&a) in main() i get error about memory allocation but i cant identify it. Using Valgrind the results its ambiguous for me to debug it. Can you help me with this specific piece of code?

Comment: `tmp_ptr = (Node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node_ptr));` is obviously wrong.

Comment: You hide a pointer type behind a `typedef`. That fires back at you when you use that type to allocate memory: `malloc(sizeof(Node_ptr));` Don't hide pointers in typedefs.

Comment: At least gcc 11.1.1 **explicitly** warns about *several* bugs in this code. Try to do some diligence before asking questions on SO.

Comment: I am new to C programming and i was confused with pointers in general! Sorry for wasting your time i should have searched more! But thanks for the guidance and the kind answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This memory allocation

```
tmp_ptr = (Node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node_ptr));
```

is wrong. You are trying to allocate an extent of memory of an incorrect size.

Try

```
tmp_ptr = (Node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

or

```
tmp_ptr = (Node_ptr)malloc(sizeof( *tmp_ptr ));
```

Also argument expressions in these calls

```
strlower(&a);
tmp = create(&a);
```

are incorrect. Instead of the type `char *` the expressions have the type `char ( * )[sizeof( a )]`.

You need to write

```
strlower( a );
tmp = create( a );
```